# how to get all user address on the transactions with a smart contract?

Tags: web3js

just started learning this and trying to get all addresses that have been interacted with a contract, I am planning to pull out all events, and then get the addresses from there? any advice if this will work? thanks

```
async function getUsers() 
    {
        var allTransactionsHash = myContract.events.allEvents.transactionHash();
        var curBlock = await web3.eth.getBlockNumber();
        var allUsers = []; 
    
        while (curBlock !== GENESIS)
        {
          var txns = web3.eth.getTransaction (allTransactionsHash);
            for (var j = 0; j < txns.length; j++) 
            {
            var txn = txns[j];
            allUsers.push(txn.from.toLowerCase(), txn.to.toLowerCase());
            }
        }
        return allUsers;
    }
```

Comment: I think you are confusing block with transaction. You could iterate a block's transactions but you cannot iterate a transaction. A few thing you may want to consider: 1/ a contract doesn't need to emit an event, 2/ a contract could execute another contract with an "internal transactin" that you couldn't retrieve with `web3.eth.getTransaction()`.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be to add events that should be emitted only for the specific functions in the contract, which you would want to track. You should always keep I'm mind that the code must be as simple and as short as possible in order to be gas-efficient.